# how to cluster same property points given the property value for each pair of strings

Tags: c#, cluster-analysis

```
0   1   1   1   1
1   0   1   1   2
1   1   0   1   2
1   1   1   0   2
1   2   2   2   0
```

The table above gives the value of a relation for each pair of strings. As you can see the matrix is symmetric(relation is commutative).Now i am supposed to find all possible groups (if subsets of a group already found are skipped it is fine.A group can have any size) such that in a given group for any possible string pair in the group the relation value is less than a particular threshold(say 2).
I've tried to do it in c# but it did not cover all possibilities and resulted in too many loops.The reason i didn't turn to any clustering algorithms is because this relation is not a distance metric.
An algorithm or a syntactic element in c# which might make the process easy or a clue about how to approach the problem...Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you show your attempted code, the input, the expected results and the results you got?

Answer (score 0):

That is quite outside my league, but I did a quick search around and found these, might give you an enlightment:

["Cluster analysis" with MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4206687/cluster-analysis-with-mysql)

This one is an article, in Portuguese though, about using the Tocher method on cluster analysys:

http://www.scielo.br/scielo.php?script=sci_arttext&pid=S0100-204X2007001000008

Sorry for not being able to help more. I'll study it, see if I can come up with something more useful

Comment: the relation i mentioned above is levenshtein distance which gives the number of edits needed to convert one string to another. It is not a distance metric. So i am not sure if clustering algorithms will help..will they?

Answer (score 0):

Not all clustering algorithms require a metric.

For example, most HAC can work with similarities as well as with distances (except for ward apparently).

Your requirement sounds *exactly* like complete linkage clustering. Even if you don't use clustering, you'll still get the same result as with HAC.

Bad news is that HAC usually is O(n^3). But I believe if you fix the threshold beforehand, it is only O(n^2).

Comment: sorry but what do you mean by HAC?

Comment: i have heard about hclust() in R. But ultimately the number of clusters should be decided by the user to cut the tree obtained from hclust.